# SQL Server 2008 Collation settings

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

We have a table where we store certain keywords and then later on we create some reports using a 3rd party tool (for which we do not have source code) which queries this table for the keywords.

Now all was working fine until we got some korean keywords, so no we have cyrillic, korean, special and normal characters

Examples

```
愚者可浹旬而學 - Korean
Æ - cyrillic
Ç - cyrillic
€ - special
A - normal
```

Our database collation is the default one - `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and the worst part is column which is storing these keywords is a `Varchar` and not `nvarchar`.

So to store all these different keywords, we changed the column to `nvarchar` but unfortunately our 3rd party tool is not finding any matches, guess its not written to work properly with `NVARCHAR`.

So the other option is to change the collation, but not sure which collation to use since we have different languages.

If I choose a collation which allows Cyrillic, it does not allow Korean and if I choose Korean it does not allow special characters, any other solution

Is there any collation that can store all three (Cyrillic, Korean, special and normal characters)?

Comment: You need to use `nvarchar` to handle this - just changing collation will not work

Comment: No other way other than using nvarchar?

Comment: No - if you need to support Cyrillic, Korean etc., `nvarchar` ***is*** the way to go.